# How to sort a grocery list automagically? (Naive machine learning)

Tags: sorting, machine-learning

I'm thinking about creating yet another grocery list app for my own needs. I want it to automagically learn in which order I tick stuff off the list. In other words: it should know which route I take through the store. Knowing that the app can sort my items for me and thus speed up my shopping.

What is the simplest solution that can possible work for this problem? I'm thinking about:

- Time the shopping trip. Start the timer when I clear the first item and stop at the last. Then calculating the average time for each item. The app can then sort items based on this calculated time.
- For each item store two lists of other items that I have ticked of before and after this item. Then sort on that somehow, don't know how though. :)

Can you think about something else? I basically want some naive machine learning for automated sorting.

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't seem like ML is a good fit for this problem.  I think you just want to know the layout of the store (bread aisle 5, milk aisle 9), and then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with simple versions of the first approach (based on times) is that it doesn't account for taking different amounts of times to go through the store: if you spend a lot of time waiting for the deli, then the times for getting eggs after that will vary a lot based on how long you waited at the deli. So ordering things based on the average time that you check them off is probably not ideal.

It would be a lot easier to do this ordering if you could figure out groups for the products, i.e. bananas and grapes are in one section and you usually get those close together, milk and eggs are in a different section that you get close together. There are some problems with this model (you might get cheddar from the fancy cheese section or from the normal section with the rest of the dairy products), but it'd be much easier to do the ordering (group A is before group B if you usually get items from group A before you get items from group B; just sort based on that, once you have the group definitions).

This could also potentially help when you enter a new item: if you've never gotten blackberries before, but your app searches the web or something to see that blackberries are more like the fruit category than the meat category, it knows to put them in the fruit group.

So, how do you do the groupings? One simple way would be to do a clustering on items in the list, using the average time difference between items as your distance measure (I'm not sure that's technically a metric, but it probably doesn't really matter). You could use k-means or any other clustering approach here. This could maybe be augmented by some kind of web- or corpus-based similarity measure, too, to be more useful for new items or in your first few runs through the store. Maybe you could use GPS data too, to help with this.

You could possibly do some kind of EM process to iterate between assigning things to groups and ordering the groups, but I'm not sure that'll be very helpful. You could also support manually assigning things to groups when this process makes a mistake.

This is a cool idea! If you release it, maybe I'll use it. :)

Comment: Grouping things make sense, thanks! I have to read up on clustering though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to just sort the list and you feel like using the average times is not good enough, you can keep lists of all the items from all your visits in the order in which you ticked off the items. Then you can sort the items in the following way:

When comparing 2 items, look at how many times you selected item A before item B. Then look at how many times you selected item B before item A and sort them based on these numbers. I.e. if you picked A before B n times and B before A m times and n>m, A should come before B. Use this comparator to sort them.

Obviously, there is a problem of what to do when n = m. This can be broken down using the average times you mentioned.

But to be honest it might be better to simply cluster them. Or maybe you can use this approach to sort them within the clusters ;)